# I installed numpy successfully but i can't seem to get it to work

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, import, nameerror

I installed numpy and wanted to create an array with it, but it always returns:

`(NameError: name 'array' is not defined)`

this is my code

```
from numpy import *
arr = array([2, 3, 4])
print(arr)
```

What's wrong and why is it not working?

Comment: It seems right, can you provide actual output from python interpreter ?

Comment: have you tried `import numpy as np` and then using `np.array`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check if numpy was correctly installed ?

```
pip show numpy
```

or

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
```

Comment: Also ```numpy.__file__``` would be useful.